# How to give custom color to antd charts treemap

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

[image]

I have integrated the antd charts treemap and its looking really bad

Comment: Please show some code of your implementation and also define 'weird', it is hard to guess what's the expected result.

Comment: https://charts.ant.design/en/examples/more-plots/treemap#drill-down

Comment: check this link please because i can't provide whole code its a lot

Comment: We can't help you, just having a working example without having the faulty code. You don't have to give the whole code, just the specific part linked to your issue.

Comment: okay let me send you code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can assign custom colors... in Chart configuration object add color property like this

```
config = {
...
    color: ({ name }) => {
      if (name === "分类 10") {
        return "lightblue";
      }
      return "red";
      // return color
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 color: ({ percentage }) => {
      if (percentage < -3) {
        return "#DC3341";
      }
      if (percentage < -2) {
        return "#B22833";
      }
      if (percentage < -1) {
        return "#80262E";
      }
      if (percentage === 0) {
        return "#1E222D";
      } else if (percentage == 1) {
        return "#1A3326";
      } else if (percentage == 2) {
        return "#80262E";
      } else {
        return "#089950";
      }
      // return color
    },
```